# Why does fuser use the STDERR?

Tags: fuser

```
SERVER:~ # fuser -uc /var/log
/var/log:             6824(daemon)  9902(root) 14011(root) 14084(root) 14208(lp)
SERVER:~ # fuser -uc /var/log 2>/dev/null
  6824  9902 14011 14084 14208SERVER:~ # 
SERVER:~ #
```

**The question:** is it because of historical reasons or are there any technical reason for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fuser` utility is bound by standards as below:

The rational for this to have diagnostic information output to `stderr`. This not only includes errors but anything that is not primary data output of the utility.
While this is useful data, if it is included in the `stdout`, then parsing the output will become increasingly difficult.

If `stdout` is being redirected or filtered, stderr still keeps printing to the terminal.

According to the [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/fuser.html), the `fuser` utility:

```
The *fuser* utility shall write to standard error additional information about the  
named  files indicating how the file is being used.
```

> *STDERR*
>
> The *fuser* utility shall write diagnostic messages to standard error.
>      The *fuser* utility also shall write the following to standard error:
>
> - The pathname of each named file is written followed immediately by a colon.
> - For each process ID written to standard output, the character 'c'
>     shall be written to standard error if the process is using the
>     file as its current directory and the character 'r' shall be
>     written to standard error if the process is using the file as
>     its root directory. Implementations may write other alphabetic
>     characters to indicate other uses of files.
> - When the **-u** option is specified, characters indicating the
>     use of the file shall be followed immediately by the user name,
>     in parentheses, corresponding to the process' real user ID.
>     If the user name cannot be resolved from the process' real user
>     ID, the process' real user ID shall be written instead of the user name.
>
> When standard output and standard error are directed to the same file,
>   the output shall be interleaved so that the filename appears at the
>   start of each line, followed by the process ID and characters
>   indicating the use of the file. Then, if the **-u** option is
>   specified, the user name or user ID for each process using that
>   file shall be written.
>
> A `<newline>` shall be written to standard error after the last
>   output described above for each file operand.

**Reference**

[IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/fuser.html)

Comment: I think he was looking for the rationale.

Comment: Updated with rational.

Answer (score 2):

It's intentional.

`fuser` outputs a "raw" format to stdout which includes only process IDs and space separators between them. This format is intended to be convenient for piping into another process or manipulating with `sed`, etc... In addition to this, it outputs extra information intended for humans to stderr, interleaved and synchronized with the stdout output. This includes the type of usage the process is making of the file and other information. The idea is that this "extra" information doesn't need to go to whatever it is that you pipe the output of `fuser` to, and by sending it to stderr, that's what happens by default.